# Rpi 3B no HDMI output

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, pi-3

Recently I've received a RPi 3 - model B on which I installed Raspbian.
After configuring the OS and adding some stuff I've shut down the Pi.
Next day I took it with me to school, from there on all screens I've tried (4 types) said no HDMI input found.

I've used:

- hdmi_force_hotplug=1
- hdmi_drive=2
- config_hdmi_boost=6 (and 4)
- hdmi_safe=1

I can confirm the SD is ok, inserted it into another Pi 3 at school, worked great. Also the ethernet port 'works' (both leds work)

Does anybody have a suggetstion?
Please?

Comment: Have you tried using different HDMI leads? Does the HDMI port look on the Pi look normal? Did the Pi work correctly before being taken to school?

Comment: I've tried 4 HDMI cables, of which I've used one before. HDMI port looks OK. Pi worked as expected

Comment: I guess it got damaged on its trip to school.

Comment: Could it...? I've protected it by putting the Pi in its original box and I didn't throw my bag around or anything like that :/ Also the pi is in a casing

Answer (score 1):

After a quick call to the company that sold them they asked me to send it back. It's probably a real HDMI defect...

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Best guess is something in the HDMI connector broke when you plugged it in or pulled it out. Sometimes the defects don't appear until they're strained once or twice.